# Stepping with gdb acts weird when encounters malloc call

Tags: c, gdb, trace

I have a simple test program, and I'm trying to get the execution flow (I need to know which source code lines are executed) through a GDB script which simply executes `step` until the end of execution. Now something weird happens: when the stepping reaches malloc function the next `step` seems to go directly to the end of execution.

The simple program is the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int f();
void g(int);

int main(void)
{
 int len = f();
 
 g(len);
 
 printf("Execution terminated\n");
 return 0;
}

int f(){
 int fvar;
 fvar = 20;
 int* farray = malloc(fvar);
 printf("Malloc executed: %p\n", farray);
 return fvar;
}

void g(int var){
 int gvar=var;
 for(int i=0;i<gvar;i++)
  var--;
}
```

Once compiled with: `gcc -O0 -g -o test test.c`

I run the GDB script with `gdb -x script`, where script is:

```
set pagination off
set logging file gdb.log
set logging on
file test
break main
run
while ( 1 )
  step
end
```

And what I get is:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1189: file test.c, line 8.

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:8
8   {
9    int len = f();
f () at test.c:17
17  int f(){
19   fvar = 20;
20   int* farray = malloc(fvar);
Malloc executed: 0x5555555592a0
Execution terminated
[Inferior 1 (process 5017) exited normally]
script:9: Error in sourced command file:
The program is not being run.
```

As you can see printf statements that come after the malloc are actually executed but it seems like the script is not stepping anymore.

I tried to issue `next` command right after the malloc and it actually prints the next line of code so it behaves differently from `step` command but obviously I can't replace `step` with `next` in the script because it won't step into my functions such as `f` and `g`.

I also tried to comment the line which contains the call to malloc and running the script with this version of the code actually prints each instruction executed until the end. But obviously this is not a fix :D

Comment: Did you find a solution? The answer below focuses on the wrong thing, as @ssbssa points out. The problem is that stepping into the malloc call doesn’t end until the end of the program. I’m having the same problem and don’t know how to solve it. Did you manage to make it stop at the printf statement?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with your script you continue to do step after the program is finished, from where the error `The program is not being run`.

You can use the solution you want but the principal is breaking the loop before the program is terminated. One solution would be to replace the `return 0;` with an `exit(0);` and  to replace the `while (1)` with a `while ($pc! = &exit)` for example or $__GI_exit. You may have a No register error, but you can avoid this error by adding   a `break exit` before run command.

An other solution is to add a `print $pc` in the loop to see the last address visited before, and  compare  directly the `$pc` to this address that you are sure it will be visited after the printf to break the loop. The pribt can be deleted once the address found. The easiest way still to use exit function when it is possible.

with the exit modification in the code. And the script modification:

```
set pagination off
set logging file gdb.log
set logging on
file exec
break main
break exit
run

while ( $pc !=  &exit)
  step
end
```

The result is :

```
101 in filedoalloc.c
Malloc executed: 0x555555756260
Execution terminated

Breakpoint 2, __GI_exit (status=0) at exit.c:139
139 exit.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git and gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0 was used for the example.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried to use that condition but I get a similar output: the only difference is "No registers" instead of "The program is not being run"

Comment: you need to add break exit before the loop( before run command). I updated my answer

Comment: I tried the first solution you suggested (adding break exit) and it tells me there's no function called "exit". Never heard of __GI_exit, by comparing it to $pc you mean something like ```while($pc != __GI_exit)``` and what is this __GI_exit exactly?

Comment: sorry, i modified your program by replacing return 0;  by exit(0);  when i tested and forgot to mention it. So it is normal to dont see exit neither __GI_exit. you compare to &__GI_exit

Comment: __GI_ is a prefix in the glibc.

Comment: Okay, I see. What if I can't modify the source code? This is just an example code but then I'll have to use this script on other files which I can't modify.

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Isn't the problem here that executing `step` on `malloc()` lets the program run until it exits, even thou it should stop at the `printf()` on the next line? I think the `while` condition has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Why it should stop at the printf? If you modify the while condition and use the exit (also replace th return with exit) or use the address it will stop whithout any error.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to do what you suggested but I'm not sure how to print the $pc of the last instruction executed because the script won't get that far. The last $pc I got printed is the malloc's one.

Comment: @yflelion I tried replacing the return with exit and yes, it gives no errors but yet it won't print the instructions executed after the malloc.

Comment: @ssbssa yes, that's the problem. I thought working on the while condition could lead to somewhere but doesn't look so in fact.

Comment: I updated my answer. whats is the gcc/gdb version you are using?

Comment: @yflelion I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0 and GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2

Comment: Did you installed libc6-dbg in your system?